# c++ Object not registered across files

Tags: c++, file-io

So I'm new to programming and basically everything I know is self-taught trough hours and hours of dumb mistakes and realizations of the same, but this is just killing me. Whenever I try compiling I get the following:

"expected primary-expression before '.' token"

The problem is probably there because I like to keep my stuff neat and therefore separated it into multiple files, and somewhere along the lines my object gets lost, or something. The following is where the error should be:

Main.cpp

```
  void start()
  {
  Player Player;            //Making the object Player, it works for the main file, but Combat.h
  int num, x, j=0;          //doesn't really like it for whatever reason.
  int stats[] = {2,3,4,5,4,1,8,5,8,7,6,5};
  int realstats[]={};
  string classes[] = {"Warrior", "Mage", "Priest", "Rogue", "Hunter", "Druid"},name;
  cin>>name;                               //Charr's name
  cin>>num;                                //class number for stat-sorting purpouses
  for(x=num*4,j;x<num*4+4;++x,++j)
  {
                    realstats[j]=stats[x];
                    }
  Player.def=realstats[0];
  Player.str=realstats[1];
  Player.agi=realstats[2];
  Player.intel=realstats[3];
  }
```

PlayerEnemy.h

```
  #include"MainHeader.h"
  #ifndef PlayerEnemy_H
  #define PlayerEnemy_H
  class Player
  {
        public:
               float att,def,str,agi,intel,HP,XP,sp,money;
               float setstat(float str,float def,float agi,float HP,float att,float sp);
               };


  class Enemy
  {
        public:
               float att,def,str,agi,intel,HP,XP,sp,money;
               float setstat(float str,float def,float agi,float HP,float att,float sp);
               };
#endif
```

Combat.h

```
#include"MainHeader.h"
#ifndef Combat_H
#define Combat_H
void Combat(int x)
{
int GG();
int y=1;
system("pause");
while(monster[x].HP>0 && Player.HP>0)
{
      if(monster[x].sp>Player.sp&&y==1)
      {
                            Player.HP-=(monster[x].att-Player.def);
                            x=0;
                            }
      if(Player.HP>0&&monster[x].HP>0) monster[x].HP-=(Player.att-monster[x].def);
      if(Player.HP>0&&monster[x].HP>0) Player.HP-=(monster[x].att-Player.def);
      }
      if(monster[x].HP<=0)
      {
                     Player.money+=monster[x].money;
                     Player.XP+=monster[x].XP;
                     }
      else GG();
      }
#endif
```

The "MainHeader.h" thingy is just a header I made that contains other headers, because I don't want first 20 lines to be just #include.

Anyways, If I re-make another object called Player from class Player in Combat.h, all works, but they don't have the same values, and If i delete the first one rest of the code goes to hell. As far as I know it should tell me that Player is already declared, so I have no idea where I went wrong.

Here's the MainHeader.h just in case I left something out... Don't think so though. But then again, it's my code that doesn't work.

```
#ifndef MainHeared_H
#define MainHeared_H

#include"PlayerEnemy.h"
#include"EnemyType.h"
#include"Combat.h"

#endif
```

Comment: What is the full error message?  It should contain the line number a file where the error occurred...

Comment: Don't ever use the `Class` name as the name of the variable! Also why would some other file know about a local variable that you declared and only exists in some other function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code in any source file can only "see" what else is in that file so far, and any included header files.  Not into other cpp files.

You have a *class name* `Player` that is defined in a header, and visible from the `Combat` function. However the *variable declaration*

```
Player Player;
```

is only visible within its scope of declaration, which is the `start()` function.  Other functions cannot see this variable, let alone other files.

When `Combat` writes something like `Player.ID`, the compiler only knows that `Player` is the name of a class, and it does not make sense to put `.` after the name of a class.

---

To fix this, the first thing to do is to stop using the same name for classes as variables. It is very confusing. For example, write:

```
Player my_player;
```

The second thing to do is to not put function code in headers. It causes undefined behaviour if you include the header more than once across the whole project. `Combat()`'s body should be in a `.cpp` file. You can put a function declaration in the header but that's all:

```
void Combat(int x);
```

If you want to have a single instance of `Player` that is visible to all code, then you have to write in a header file:

```
extern Player global_player;
```

and then in *one* of the `.cpp` files, outside of any function body:

```
Player global_player;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    Player Player;  // this is wrong

Player player  // this is OK
```

You should not use a type name as an identifier.

```
Player.def=realstats[0];  // "expected primary-expression before '.' token"
```

are you are referring to an object or the class it self??

Comment: note, it is legal to use the same identifier for a type name as for a variable name (and the variable name shadows the type name). It is very bad style of course.